# Detect specific devices within android application

Tags: java, android

Is there a way of telling, within the application the spcific device model that the app is being run from. For example for it to be able to tell the difference if the app is running on a Nexus S or a HTC Desire or the Samsung Galaxy Tab?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This give name of overall product

```
android.os.Build.PRODUCT
```

You can also try others by Build.*

Comment: Thank you, literally as I was about to check back on here I found the answer. Is there any difference between using Build.PRODUCT and Build.MODEL?